# Monit not monitoring LEMP

Tags: nginx, mysql

I have LEMP with MariaDB installed on Ubuntu 14.04. I have Monit installed and configured to monitor php-fpm, mysqld and nginx but non of these services seem to be monitored as shown in the screenshot here:

[image]

I have configuration files for each service that i want monitored in the `/etc/moninit/conf.d/`
The directory is properly included in /etc/monit/monitrc using the following line:

```
include /etc/monit/conf.d/*
```

Here are my configuration file contents for Mysql

```
check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   group database
   group mysql
   start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
   stop  program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
   if failed host localhost port 3306 protocol mysql with timeout 15 seconds for 3 times within 4 cycles then restart
   if failed unixsocket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock protocol mysql for 3 times within 4 cycles then restart
   if 5 restarts with 5 cycles then timeout
   depend mysql_bin
   depend mysql_rc

 check file mysql_bin with path /usr/sbin/mysqld
   group mysql
   include /etc/monit/templates/rootbin

 check file mysql_rc with path /etc/init.d/mysql
   group mysql
   include /etc/monit/templates/rootbin
```

Comment: Have you considered users and permissions? I have monit running as root and it works fine. I don't monitor MySQL, as in AWS RDS hitting the port without a valid client repeatedly caused it to block the server. My monit configuration is here https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#monit

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I did not change anything and I just ran ps aux|grep monit and it shows the process is running as root

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it on my own. For some reason:

```
sudo monit monitor all
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: I kindly ask that the thread be marked closed

Comment: You have to do that yourself.